# vue.js nuxt.js Creating dynamical pages and pagination

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have several scenes that I want to include in my nuxt project.

The project should have pages, and each page has 4 scenes.

I'm currently 'coding' each page and import the scenes manually.

This is my pages tree:
pages tree
[image: pages tree]

This is my first page

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <Scene1 />
    <Scene2 />
    <Scene3 />
    <!-- <Scene4 /> -->
  </main>
</template>

<script>

import Scene1 from './1/Scene1.vue'
import Scene2 from './1/Scene2.vue'
import Scene3 from './1/Scene3.vue'
// import Scene4 from './1/Scene4.vue'


export default {
   components: {
    Scene1,
    Scene2,
    Scene3,
    // Scene4
  }
}

</script>




<style scoped>

.main{

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;

}

</style>
```

And this is how a scene looks like:

```
<template>  
    <div class="three-item">
        <div class="item-title">
            Color Rectangle
        </div>
<p>Vertex</p>
<pre><code id="vertexShader">
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
}

</code></pre>
<p>Fragment</p>
<pre><code id="fragmentShader">
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;

void main() {
    // Magenta (1,0,1)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
}
        </code></pre>
        <div id="scene1" class="scene">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Three from 'three'

import hljs from 'highlight.js'
import glsl from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/glsl';

export default{

    name: 'Scene1',

    data() {
        return {
            camera: null,
            scene: null,
            renderer: null,
            mesh: null
        }
    },

    methods: {


        init: function() {

            this.container = document.getElementById('scene1');

            this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(70, this.container.clientWidth/this.container.clientHeight, 0.01, 10);
            this.camera.position.z = 1;

            this.scene = new Three.Scene();


            this.uniforms = {
                u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
                u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new Three.Vector2() },
                u_mouse: { type: "v2", value: new Three.Vector2() }
            };

            let material = new Three.ShaderMaterial( {
                uniforms: this.uniforms,
                vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
            } );


            let geometry = new Three.BoxBufferGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
            // let material = new Three.MeshNormalMaterial();

            this.mesh = new Three.Mesh(geometry, material);
            this.scene.add(this.mesh);

            this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({alpha:true});

            this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);

            this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.onWindowResize, false );


            hljs.registerLanguage('glsl', glsl);

            document.querySelectorAll('pre code').forEach((block) => {
                hljs.highlightBlock(block);
            });
        },

        animate: function() {

            requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
            this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
            this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

            this.uniforms.u_time.value += 0.05;

            this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

        },

        onWindowResize: function() {

            this.camera.aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight;
            this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);

        }

    },
    mounted() {
        this.init();
        this.animate();
        this.onWindowResize();
    }
}
</script>
```

To be honest, I don't get behind the dynamical created pages with nuxt. Is there a way to have a template that fetches 4 scenes, puts them into a page and does it all over again? It could be that I want to add scenes in the middle of the pages. That would destroy my current setup.

My goal is to have something like this:

dreams tree
[image: dreams tree]

the page.vue is crawling through the scenes, picks 4, creates a page called '1', and does it all over again. Can someone lend me a hand with that? In the examples at the nuxt homepage they use .json files. I already set up all three.js scenes, but these have javascript files in it.

Erik

Comment: if its a page component, it goes in the components folder

Comment: These are not components. I don't want to reuse the scenes. They only appear once.

Comment: The components directory contains your Vue.js Components. The pages directory contains your Application Views and Routes. The framework reads all the .vue files inside this directory and creates the application router. Its not about if you use them multiple times, placing components in pages folder **will create routes**. RTM: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure

Comment: Maybe your after child-routes: https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-child/

Comment: Ok, well, I moved all scenes to the components folder. :s